# MSAL / MS Graph code works in .Net Core 3.1 but not .Net Framework 4.8

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Have an application which is managing users in Azure ADB2C using the client credential flow. App is written in .Net Framework and has been using ADAL to communicate with ADB2C. Currently looking to migrate the app away from ADAL to MSAL but have encountered a problem as follows.

If I create a simple .Net Core 3.1 sample app and use the code below then the app will connect to ADB2C and list the users.

If I use the same code in a sample .Net Framework 4.8 console app then the code will exit the app with no exception, no error etc when it tries to execute the **"await graphClient.Users.Request()"** command. No indication of any issue but it just exits out...
It never reaches the next line to enumerate the result. If I debug and step through, same thing happens, program crashes at that line with no error/exception.

UPDATE:: This appears to be an issue on the corporate environment it runs in. If I take the same code and run on my personal laptop against personal Azure resources it works for both .Net Framework and .Net Core versions.

The question now becomes what is different about the request as emitted by the .net framework version as against the .net core version. Using Fiddler the code can be seen issuing a CONNECT login.microsoftonline.com:443, for the .net framework version the session is aborted whereas the .net core call continues on to communicate with the ADB2C resource etc.

Any ideas?

---

Migrating the app to .Net Core is not an option at the moment so need to get the .Net Framework app working with MSAL.

Can't see what the issue is, the code presumably *should* work but it doesn't in .Net Framework.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
```

```
var clientId = "app client id";
var clientSecret = "app secret";
var tenantId = "myownb2cdomain.onmicrosoft.com";

IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
                    .Create(clientId)
                    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
                    .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
                    .Build();

ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var result = await graphClient.Users // Program crashes here with no exception or error given
                    .Request()
                    .Select(e => new
                    {
                        e.DisplayName,
                        e.Id,
                        e.Identities
                    })
                    .GetAsync();

foreach (var user in result.CurrentPage)
{
    Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
}
```

Current Nuget package versions as follows

```
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph" version="3.26.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Auth" version="1.0.0-preview.6" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="1.24.0" targetFramework="net48" />
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue with .net framework. Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: @winterishere unfortunately the issue just "went away" when I created a new solution/project with same code, same package references etc. It worked in the new project but not in the old... no idea why

Comment: So here it is July, 2022, and I've just tried this code with .Net6 Core in VS2022 with the same results.  It exits on the `graphClient.Users.Request() [...] .GetAsync();  Microsoft.Graph.Auth is now deprecated, and is replaced by Azure.Identity, So there is that difference between my code and yours.  Very puzzling.  I also am running this against a corporate Azure environment.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the code. I test it in my side to list users by msal. When the code run with .net core 3.1, it can print the result in the line `Console.WriteLine(...)`. But if the code run with .net framework 4.8, it will exit the app as you mentioned.

Actually, when it runs in .net framework 4.8, it also print the result. We can add a line of code `Console.ReadLine();`, then you can see the result in console.

Below is my code for your reference:

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Graph.Auth;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{
    class Program
    {
        static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConfidentialClientApplication confidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create("clientId")
            .WithTenantId("tenantId")
            .WithClientSecret("clientSecret")
            .Build();

            ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(confidentialClientApplication);

            GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

            var users = await graphClient.Users
            .Request()
            .GetAsync();

            Console.WriteLine(users.Count);
            
            Console.ReadLine(); //add this line, then the console window will not exit
        }
    }
}
```

Another way, if you do not want to add the line `Console.ReadLine();`. You can use "**Ctrl + F5**" instead of click "**Start**" button to run your code, it will also show the console result.

============================**Update**============================

```
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph" version="3.27.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Auth" version="1.0.0-preview.6" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Graph.Core" version="1.24.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Identity.Client" version="4.27.0" targetFramework="net48" />
```

Comment: I've hopefully made my question clearer to indicate that the code crashes at **graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync()** . It never reaches the next line, in your case the Console.WriteLine or in mine the enumeration of the result. It is the crash is the issue. Your code works for you. The difference "might" be the versions of the nuget packages. I've added the versions I currently have to the question, can you compare to yours and let me know which versions are in use for you?

Comment: Hi @briask I'm sorry that misunderstood your question. I test with same code you provided in my side just now, it works fine. I have updated my answer with the nuget packages in my project.

Comment: @briask By the way, how did you know the code just reaches the line `graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync()` but not execute the next line ? As in my test, if we run the code in .net framework, it will run success but will not keep the console window for a long time. So I suggest you to add the line `Console.ReadLine();` in my original answer.

Comment: @briask [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxpzS.png) is my code(which is almost same with yours except the last line) for your reference. It works fine.

Comment: @briask I'm sorry, but could you please have a try with add the line `Console.ReadLine();` or run your code by "Ctrl + F5". Because your code and nuget packages seems correct, so I guess the code works fine in your side. The problem is the console window doesn't keep.

Comment: OK. so this code is running inside a corporate environment. Ran the same code on my personal laptop against my personal Azure ADB2C and it works... Something in the corporate environment is causing the issue.

Comment: @briask So have you tried add the line of code `Console.ReadLine();` when you run inside corporate environment ?

Comment: yes and it makes no difference. My query has always been around the code crashing at the graphClient.Users.Request().GetAsync() command, it never reaches any code past that request. have confirmed this by using the debugger and adding lines of code.

Comment: Hi @briask I have upload my code to [github](https://github.com/HuryShen/ConsoleApp8), you can download it and test.